# Accessing "columns" of 2d lists in dart

Tags: list, dart, syntax, nested, 2d

In a nested list, you can access what semantically would be "rows" by calling the nested list's indices as if it was one-dimensional:

```
//some nested list of type List<List<dynamic>>

print(nested)
//[["ColumnName0", "ColumnName1"], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

print(nested[0])
//["ColumnName0, "ColumnName1"]
```

Is there a similar shorthand to get ["ColumnName0", 0, 0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a shorthand, but should work:

```dart
nested.map((s) => s[0]).toList()
```